# Pivot source with SQL vs. Table source with SQL and then Pivot based on the table

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, query

If I want to pull SQL data into a Pivot table, what will be quicker and more efficient?

1. To have the data pulled into a regular table (which I want to present anyway) and then create the Pivot based on this table.
2. To have data pulled simultaneously into a table and into a Pivot table.

Regarding point 2, does it use the same query for both? When I try to change the Pivot table's data source into the already existing table connection, it just duplicates the connections and thus I have 2 identical workbook connections, "Query from X" and "Query from X1". Does it mean it calls the same query twice?

Comment: Excel itself has Built-in facility,,, Go to DATA TAB, and hit Get External Data then Click From Other Sources, you find the drop down menu the First option is, From SQL Server just click & follow the procedure. Other is POwer Query.

Comment: Not sure how that relates to my question because I already use the built-in facility. I also use SQL to pull data into a table. But when I select the same connection to a Pivot, then it's as if it duplicates it. So my question is does it actually run the same query twice? Is it faster to run the query both in a table and in a Pivot or to run it just to a table and then build the Pivot from this table?

Comment: *"Is it faster to run the query both in a table and in a Pivot or to run it just to a table and then build the Pivot from this table?"* ... Have you timed it out doing it both ways yet and see which way is faster? This seems like something you can confirm without needing someone to tell you otherwise.

Comment: @LWC, I've never experienced what you are talking about, hardly seen that excel runs Query or Formula even twice, unless is not be set to do so.